# Rig is created using Rigify if you find a layer with ORG bones in it?

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I study different rigs and often come across the fact that there is a layer with ORG bones in the rig.

So it became interesting to me - If there is an ORG of bones, then does this mean that the rig was created with the participation of Rigify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily.   It *usually* means that the rig was generated, because the most common use of the `ORG` prefix is to identify the bones as they existed in the model rig.  There are many other add-ons that generate rigs from a mode and keep the original bones with the `ORG` prefix added, and at least one rigger has said on Blender StackExchange that they use the `ORG` prefix for other purposes.

Prefixes and suffixes are just naming conventions and there's no standard.  Other than the use of the left/right convention to support mirroring, Blender doesn't use any naming conventions internally, so it's entirely up to the rigger what conventions they use.

Comment: I understand that there is no standard for prefixes. But, perhaps, there is some conditional standard by which most people work.

Comment: The industry tends to be secretive and so each studio that does rigging has a naming convention that it uses, but they don't really share.  Still, some prefixes do get used consistently, just because they're obvious shortenings of the use of the bone, like DEF being used for deforming bones.